# Comparing URLS in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

Whats another way to compare URLs? This is not working.  Its been a really long while since i've coded

```
var myURL = 
(window.location.href="http://randbox.blogspot.com/2014/01/test-0.html");
if ( alert(document.URL) == myURL ) {
```

Comment: Store the URL in a database and retrieve it with ajax? Aside from a non-static link what's wrong with a simple if statement?

Comment: The if statement is not working for me

Comment: Well for one, you're comparing an alert() to a variable.

Comment: my first thought was this window.location.host

Comment: Simple debugging will tell you which one you want

Comment: Note that `window.location.href="http://randbox.blogspot.com/2014/01/test-0.html"` reloads the page with the new URL. So whatever code you put after that statement is potentially not executed anyway. If you'd explain what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myURL = 
(window.location.href="http://randbox.blogspot.com/2014/01/test-0.html");
if ( document.URL == myURL ) {
```

Remove the `alert()` function. It's not comparable to a variable, so it will return false.

If it still doesn't work, document.URL might not be what you're wanting, or the string is incorrect, or maybe both are wrong.

Comment: Yeah i got to wait 1 min it says thanks again :)